# get value input text vue using cypress

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cypress, e2e-testing

thank you for reading my question.

I want to ask about how to get value some input text who that value set by virtual dom/data binding in react/vue or maybe another lib/framework.

In my mind, a cypress is a tool for e2e testing. so that's why we can't get this value. I also check the component that I want to get by inspecting that element, and I can't get some attribute for getting  my value.

[image: screen shoot of question get value input text vue using cypress]

idk but what should i do but i need to get this value. please tell me if you know this answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it by using the `invoke('val')` method, something like:

```js
cy.get('#input_text_employee_name')
  .invoke('val')
  .then((val) => {
    cy.log(val) //prints hi@there.com
  })
```

You can also apply an assertion with `should('have.value')` like this:

```js
cy.get('#input_text_employee_name').should('have.value', 'hi@there.com')
```